# Rails 5 - Can't verify CSRF token authenticity - Only sometimes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails 5 app and am using a form to submit data. I am using CSRF protection and the form generates a hidden field `'authenticity_token'`. Works great!

But sometimes a user gets and error `'Can't verify CSRF token authenticity'`. And I am wondering why this happens? I can only imagine that the user has cookies disabled. But which normal internet user does that? Are there any other reasons?

I am not able to reproduce this error on my computer. So the only solution I have is to disable CSRF protection which is not really what I would like to do.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is this an error you caught in your logs or through user feedback? Either way, you shouldn't disable CSRF protection. It seems like it is doing its job...especially considering you can't reproduce the error and it only happens occasionally. I'd make sure those requests are valid before doing anything.

Comment: User report me the error, I then go and check and find the error in the log. I am sure that the users are not trying to attack the system. It's a booking platform and after reporting the error, the user books offline. That's why I know that they are actually trying to book in the app.

Answer (score 0):

`Can't verify CSRF token authenticity` results in `500 Internal Server`.

> I am wondering why this happens? I can only imagine that the user has cookies disabled. But which normal internet user does that? Are there any other reasons?

Yes, this happens. Or maybe the user(or hacker) tries to make an API request to the endpoint and since, it can't verify the authenticity token it will throw this error. A normal user doesn't do this, but maybe someone who values their privacy and may turn these settings off, or maybe they want to use Tor browser and so on. As developers, all we can do is try to provide best possible experience to the end user.

---

So, A better practice is to catch `500 Internal Server` error with some custom message and then display it to the end user, while also sending the `Stack trace` to yourself(slack notification etc.) so that you can work on if it's a critical issue.

This way, If everything is good from user's end, this will work normally. But If someone disables cookies(or anything that results in some error), you can display custom message about the issue.